# Problem with Counter Strike Global Offensive

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I am having a problem with Counter Strike Global Offensive. I just bought a new DVD of it, and installed it without a problem at installation.
Now I am trying to open the game using the desktop icon, but when game reaches the main menu, it freezes and after few seconds, it closes.  I get no message about why it happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter Strike:Global Offensive only works with steam. That being said, you need to download and install a little software here:

> www.steampowered.com

After you have created an account and installed the software, you need to start up steam and on bottom left click "Activate retail game" after doing so , enter the serial key which came along your DVD and press enter. Now it will validate and associate the game with your account.

Notes:

> You cannot play multiplayer even if you get the game working without steam.
>
> If you do not have serial key w/ your DVD contact retailer.

Comment: can I play it without steam. Is it necessary?

Comment: You see valve is the owner of steam and counter strike. All multiplayer servers for CS:GO are owned by valve an so even to play it in single player you need to install steam. There are workarounds like cracks but they won't let you play online on steam servers.

Comment: I also want help in these issue.

Comment: Call of duty ghost Dx11[link](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/168344/call-of-duty-ghost-dx10) Splinter Cell Conviction [link](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/168343/problem-with-splinter-cell-conviction)