# Problem with Splinter Cell Conviction

Tags: windows-7, splinter-cell-conviction

I am having two problems with Splinter Cell:Conviction.

- First problem with this game is about resolution. My monitor doesn't support its original resolution. I need to change it to default.  Is there any way to change it without opening game?
- Second problem with this game is, when it reaches the main menu, then the game window automatically minimizes. I tried to open it again, but it didn't work; same happened as before. I can hear sound of main menu.

One more thing, that game was working before on Windows 7 32bit version but now I have Windows 7 64bit. Does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

To fix resolution, go to:

> C:\ProgramData\Ubisoft\Conviction
>   open the ConvictionUserPC.ini and find and change
>
> FullscreenViewportX= change (width like 1360)
>   FullscreenViewportY= change (height like 768)

As for the second problem , try to run the game in windowed mode, if that dosen't work out, then open taskmanager and put splinter.exe on high priority.

Note : Make sure you run as Administrator.